# How to fix the problem: when localizing values from an array using the i18next library, I get undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next

How to fix the problem: when localizing values from an array using the i18next library, I get undefined?

State setting:

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        language: '',
        errors: new Map([
          ['EmptyInputError', i18next.t('welcome')]
        ])
      }
  }
```

Function show error:

```
  showError = (error) => {
    document.getElementById("showError").style.opacity = "1";
    let getError = this.state.errors.get(error);
    document.getElementById("showError").innerHTML = getError;
  }
```

Comment: Just tried it and didn’t get any error message. Where do you call `showError` and what argument are you passing it ? Also, you shouldn’t use DOM parsing code, such as `document.`, when coding in React, as the framework is designed to avoid that.

Comment: @KawaLo this.showError('EmptyInputError') . displays undefined in message

Comment: Did you bind your function ? (in constructor, `this.showError = this.showError.bind(this)`. It’ll be great if you could post your whole component code, instead of just the constructor. Since I’m perfectly able to do what you want in my code, I strongly believe your issue lies somewhere else inside your component.

Comment: @KawaLo Yep, i tryed binded it. Nothing to get. This is different. When I put instead `['EmptyInputError', i18next.t('welcome')]` for example `['EmptyInputError', 'test']`, everything will be perfectly displayed

Comment: Is i18next working in other parts of your code  ? (like in a render for example) And is it properly imported ? I’ve tried a copy past of your code (with i18next) and I still can’t get any error. Is ‘welcome’ a valid key in your translation file ?

Comment: @KawaLo It works when I put this MAP array in the showError function.`welcome` is a valid key in my translation file. Can you upload your file on codeopen for example? And indicate this in the reply to this post.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle : https://codesandbox.io/s/i18next-map-fiddle-tmrop?fontsize=14. Have a look at `i18n.js` and `container.jsx`

Comment: I just had to initialize in the constructor ..